# How to set default.region and default.output with ENV vars

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, environment-variables, dockerfile

I have this:

```
ENV AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID 'AKIA5Jxxxxxxx2CNT74UI'
ENV AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY  '9Dot6OPhxxxxxxxOlB8NlFlK3k1vKEXm'

RUN aws configure set default.region us-west-2
RUN aws configure set default.output json
```

how do I make the 3rd and 4th lines into ENV vars instead of requiring the aws cli? I know it just writes it to .aws/credentials, but looking to just use ENV vars here instead of the file(s).

Answer (score 0):

According to these docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html

this should be right:

```
ENV AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID='AKIA5JxcxxxxxxCNT74UI'
ENV AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY='9Dot6OPhz8ckxxxxxxxxlFlK3k1vKEXm'
ENV AWS_DEFAULT_REGION='us-west-2'
ENV AWS_DEFAULT_OUTPUT='json'
```